# SSIS 2008 execute DTS 2000 package with variable

Tags: ssis, dts

I have a for each loop that populates from a set of flat files into a  Sql Server table,  I run the Flat file Import via  a dts package embedded into  Execute DTS 2000 Task. I want to pass the Sourcefile Name that is fetched by the For Each Loop to assign it Global Variable in DTS. how this can be made ?

Thanks
Manu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "Outer Variables" in the edit menu for your DTS 2000 task. We just set a package scoped variable of the same name and selected it from the drop-down on that page. Passed through fine.